# Furnace making a loud cracking noise when starting

Tags: furnace

My furnace has started making a loud cracking noise when it starts up.

It still seems to be working, as far as I can tell, and the noise does not happen after the furnace lights up.

I made a recording of the furnace turning on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6ZGyhkbbIY. The noise happens at around 0:32 and again at 1:18.

Any ideas? (And sorry if this is a wrong place to post?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I certainly would *not* cal the noise you recorded "cracking", which is like the sound of something breaking, such as bending glass until it cracks.

That said, this "creaking", or "buzzing", as I'd describe it, seems like a bearing  binding with [stick-slip vibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stick-slip_phenomenon), or perhaps the impeller of the black plastic centrifugal blower hitting a part before it gets up to speed.

Another possibility is [relay chatter](https://askinglot.com/what-causes-relay-chatter), which makes noise as the armature vibrates. AC relays are more prone to chatter.

You might use a piece of plastic tubing, held to the ear, to find what part is making the noise.

If it is the blower, then you might try loosening and removing the plastic impeller, putting a few drops of automotive engine oil on the shaft at the bearing. Look for scratches on the back of the impeller, to see if it's rubbing against a part, and if needed, adjust the part hitting it. Reattach the impeller and check that everything works.

Answer (score 0):

If the sound is better described as a steady clicking it would be the igniter which will start prior to the gas valve opening.  If your furnace has an inspection window you may be able to confirm this by watching the startup.  I'd describe that sound as "tic-tic-tic".